# AFNetworking and multiple UIImageViews pulling from same URL

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage, nsdata, afnetworking

I have an issue where im loading 3, sometimes 4 of the same images using

`[imageFile setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:friendAvatar] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultProfileImage.png"]];`

Im trying to see if theres a way to load this into some kind of NSData and use it later on, kind of like how im doing below, but using AFNetworking.

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0 ), ^(void)
                   {
                       NSURL *url3 = [NSURL URLWithString:friendAvatar];
                       NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url3];
                       UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                       dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                           imageFile.image = img;
                           bgImageFile.image = img;
                       });
                   });
```

Also im not calling the image loads all in the same method, 2 call under the cellForRowAtIndexPath once the users friends list has been populated, then the 3rd gets loaded when i swipe over a cell to show its hidden (under) layer, the 4th repeat image gets called when pressing a button that is showed once the cell has been swiped which leads to a chatroom view between me and that friend.

Hopefully i got to my point on what im trying to acheive. And any help pointing in the right direction is very much appreciated.

**Update:**

This is my current code, this is what i mean by im pulling the same image several times.

Inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
[imageFile setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultProfileImage.png"]];
[bgImageFile setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:friendAvatar] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultProfileImage.png"]];
```

The method `bottomDrawerWillAppear` that is called contains

```
UIImageView *drawerBGImg = [[UIImageView alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,75)];
NSString *friendAvatar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", @"http://v9a2a7.com/user_photos/", [MyClass friendID], @".jpg"];
[drawerBGImg setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:friendAvatar]];
```

And on a seperate class and seperate view `viewMessageViewController`

```
NSString *friendAvatar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", @"http://v9a2a7.com/user_photos/", email, @".jpg"];
[bgImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:friendAvatar]];
```

I have not confirmed that the `viewMessageViewsController`'s forces the image to be pulled from the server, but i know for a fact on the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` makes 3 requests for the same image which results in using 3X the amount of data usage

Hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to cache the image so you don't have to keep loading it.  Assuming that's what you mean...

The AFNetworking method `[UIImageView -setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:]` already caches this image for you.  The second time you call it, the image will be loaded from the cache.

The only reason it would get reloaded from the server a second time is if your app receives a low memory warning since the last download. (`AFImageCache`, an `NSCache` subclass, will automatically invalidate some or all of the cache.)

It uses the URL as the key, so as long as the URL is identical, the image will only get loaded from the server once.

Comment: If you're using the code extensively, you might want to take a look here and see how it works.  It's less than 200 lines of code, so it's a pretty quick read: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.m

Comment: After more review i found out my issue was a combination of my new server i moved to not having correct cache headers. However, i do have another issue regarding when the app closes and when the app is put into the background, the images are then released. Is this standard practice of AFNetworking considering how iOS typically releases the apps memory once its forced into the background?

Comment: @AaronRussell NSCache only saves stuff during the lifetime of the app.  If you'd like to cache to disk, I suggest taking a look at SDWebImage, which will allow you to easily cache the images to disk.

Comment: I like to keep things on one framework, so would it be possible to make AFNetworking cache to the disk? I suppose i can take a look at both the Frameworks and see where the cachePolicy are different? Im also going to delete this question since theres no usefull information to it to anyone else and it was a common known error that someone would have to read the comments to find out. (In other words, useless post/question)

Comment: It's possible, just edit `AFNetworking+UIImageView.m` and add some disk caching code.